# How to filter results by media type in php for google-photos-api?

Tags: php, google-photos-api

I am building a filter in a simmilair way to the sample project on git hub: https://github.com/google/php-photoslibrary/blob/samples/src/filters/index.php

```
$filtersBuilder = new FiltersBuilder();
    $filtersBuilder ->setMediaType(MediaType::PHOTO);

    $response = $photosLibraryClient->listMediaItems(['filters' => $filtersBuilder->build()]);
    $return_images = [];
    foreach ($response->getPage()->getIterator() as $item) {
        // Get some properties of a media item
        /* @var $item \Google\Photos\Library\V1\MediaItem */
        $image['url'] = $item->getBaseUrl();
        $image['id'] = $item->getId();
        $return_images[] = $image;
    }
    return $return_images;
```

The first result i get back is a video with a mime_type: video/mp4.

What am i doing wrong?

EDIT: solved! The problem was that i should have used `$photosLibraryClient->searchMediaItems(['filters' => $filtersBuilder->build()]);`

Instead of
 `$photosLibraryClient->listMediaItems(['filters' => $filtersBuilder->build()]);`

Comment: And you don't want `video/mp4`? Just from looking at `$filtersBuilder ->setMediaType(MediaType::VIDEO);` I'd expect it to return videos.

Comment: Absolutly right, but that wasnt the problem, i was playing with it for testing and copied the wrong version. Corrected now.